# Using Ant to ensure a properties file only contains unique entries

Tags: ant, build-process, automation, internationalization, build-automation

Is there a way in Ant which can check that a specified properties file only contains unique keys? A build failure would be the required behaviour if any duplicates are found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[rscbundlecheck](http://rscbundlecheck.sourceforge.net/) does the duplicate key check and more validations suitable for internationalization. Blurb from their website:

> Ant Task for checking Java
>   Resourcebundles. It checks for
>   existence of all keys in each bundle,
>   duplicate keys, existence of forbidden
>   chars (e.g. special characters like
>   umlauts) and continuous usage of
>   placeholders.

Example ant script:

```
<taskdef name="resourceCheck" classpathref="build.classpath" classname="org.dyndns.fichtner.rsccheck.ant.RscBundleCheckTask"/>
<resourceCheck>
    <fileset file="my-properties-file.properties"/>
</resourceCheck>
```

Where **build.classpath** contains the resourceCheck binary jar available [here](http://sourceforge.net/project/showfiles.php?group_id=212749&package_id=256018)